Calculate days in between status change
I'm not sure how to code to get the result I'm looking for. I hope the community can point me in the right direction. I need to run a report against the Rent History table, and I expect the report to look like the Final Result. Please see the image for details.

There are three tags in the Rent History table. I was able to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) to determine the On/Off Rent start date based on the position. This is where I stopped because I'm not sure what to do next. So far, this is the code that I have.
SELECT tag
,progress_complete_date_time
,create_date
,required_until_date
,modify_date
,on_rent_status
,[date_on-off_rent]
,position
,CASE 
    WHEN position = 1
        THEN [date_on-off_rent]
    END AS [first_time_on-off_rent]
,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tag  ORDER BY modify_date) AS [RANK]
FROM CleanUpB

The DateOnRent and DateOffRent columns are based on how the tags start out. Some tags start with DateOnRent and some with DateOffRent. I only need to capture the start and end status of on_rent_status.
Here is my formula to calculate DaysOnRent and DaysOffRent.

TAG-000479 DaysOnRent
DATEDIFF(DAY,'8/12/2021','4/4/2024') = 966
DATEDIFF(DAY,'04/04/2024','06/10/2024') = 67


TAG-000479 DaysOffRent
DATEDIFF(DAY,'04/04/2024','04/04/2024') = 0
DATEDIFF(DAY,'06/10/2024',GETDATE()) = 38


TAG-001832 DaysOnRent
DATEDIFF(DAY,'03/28/2024',GETDATE()) = 112


TAG-003420 DaysOnRent
DATEDIFF(DAY,'06/24/2024',GETDATE()) = 24


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Are all those columns needed to reproduce the actual problem? Make it easy to assist you, simplify - [mcve].

Updated version
Based on feedback from OP. This is not just a simple min/max situation, it's a gaps and islands problem. In this case, we have to deal with multiple "on_rent" records and potentially multiple "off_rent" records as well as gaps in between "off_rent" and "on_rent".
This is my solution so far (see bottom of response to populate sample data table):
WITH cte AS (
    -- Collapse groups to get the start and end rent dates for each
    SELECT x.tag, x.GroupID
        , DateOnRent  = MIN(IIF(x.on_rent_status = 1, x.[date_on-off_rent], NULL)) -- Using min because we want the FIRST time  on_rent was logged
        , DateOffRent = MIN(IIF(x.on_rent_status = 0, x.[date_on-off_rent], NULL)) -- Using min because we want the FIRST time off_rent was logged
    FROM (
        SELECT x.tag, x.[date_on-off_rent], x.on_rent_status
            -- If the status changed from off_rent to on_rent, then we know a new group has started
            -- Returning 1 to the running total will generate a grouping ID that keeps sequential rent_status records together
            , GroupID = SUM(IIF(x.on_rent_status = 1 AND x.prev_on_rent_status = 0, 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY x.tag ORDER BY x.position)
        FROM (
            SELECT tag, on_rent_status, [date_on-off_rent], position
                -- Getting the previous value will help us later determine whether the status changed
                , prev_on_rent_status = LAG(on_rent_status) OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY position)
            FROM #rent_history
        ) x
    ) x
    GROUP BY x.tag, x.GroupID
)
SELECT x.tag
    , FirstDateOnRent = MIN(x.DateOnRent)
    , LastDateOffRent = MAX(x.LastDateOffRent) -- NULL if still on_rent
    , DaysOnRent      = SUM(x.DaysOnRent)
    , DaysOffRent     = DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(x.LastDateOffRent), GETDATE()) -- NULL if still on_rent
FROM (
    SELECT x.tag, x.DateOnRent, x.DateOffRent
        -- We want the most recent state of DateOffRent, rather than MAX, which means if they are still on_rent, it should return null
        , LastDateOffRent = LAST_VALUE(x.DateOffRent) OVER (PARTITION BY x.tag ORDER BY x.DateOnRent)
        -- Number of DaysOnrent needs to be calc'd at the group level so we don't accidentally include gaps
        , DaysOnRent  = DATEDIFF(DAY, x.DateOnRent, COALESCE(x.DateOffRent, GETDATE()))
    FROM cte x
) x
GROUP BY x.tag;

I tried to comment the code as best I could, so I won't completely dive into how this works line by line.
But the basic idea is...calculate some sort of grouping ID that can keep sequential events together. In this case I relied on both LAG() and SUM({state change logic}) OVER() to generate that ID.
Then from there it's just a lot of extra grouping and aggregation to get the final output.
This new query version will support multiple on_rent records, multiple off_rent records as well as gaps between off_rent and on_rent.

Old/Original reply
Based on your explanation, you have a table/dataset called "Rent History", which represents the top dataset in your screenshot.
And you want a query against that dataset whose output matches the second dataset in your screenshot labeled "Final Result".
Assuming that's true, this is what I've come up with...problem is, I'm making a bunch of assumptions around business logic that may not be correct, even if it does match your output table...
SELECT x.tag, x.DateOnRent, x.DateOffRent
    , DaysOnRent  = DATEDIFF(DAY, x.DateOnRent, COALESCE(x.DateOffRent, GETDATE()))
    , DaysOffRent = DATEDIFF(DAY, x.DateOffRent, GETDATE())
FROM (
    SELECT tag
        , DateOnRent  = MIN(IIF(on_rent_status = 1, [date_on-off_rent], NULL))
        , DateOffRent = MAX(IIF(on_rent_status = 0, [date_on-off_rent], NULL))
    FROM #rent_history
    GROUP BY tag
) x

I also don't know how large the underlying datasets are this is running against, so I have no idea how efficient it would be.
The concept seems pretty simple though...grab the earliest "on_rent" date and the oldest "off_rent" date. Then do the datediff calculations using those?

For anyone who wants the script I used to generate the sample data...
CREATE TABLE #rent_history (
    tag                         nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    progress_complete_date_time datetime     NOT NULL,
    create_date                 datetime     NOT NULL,
    required_until_date         datetime     NOT NULL,
    modify_date                 datetime     NOT NULL,
    on_rent_status              bit          NOT NULL,
    [date_on-off_rent]          datetime     NOT NULL,
    position                    int          NOT NULL,
    [first_time_on-off_rent]    datetime         NULL,
    [RANK]                      int          NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO #rent_history
VALUES ('TAG-000479', '08/12/21 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', '01/31/24 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', 1, '08/12/21 00:00', 1, '08/12/21 00:00', 1)
     , ('TAG-000479', '08/12/21 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', '01/31/24 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', 1, '11/06/23 00:00', 2, NULL            , 1)
     , ('TAG-000479', '08/12/21 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', '01/31/24 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', 1, '11/06/23 00:00', 3, NULL            , 1)
     , ('TAG-000479', '08/12/21 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', '04/01/24 00:00', '04/04/24 05:00', 0, '04/04/24 00:00', 4, NULL            , 4)
     , ('TAG-000479', '08/12/21 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', '04/01/24 00:00', '04/04/24 05:00', 1, '04/04/24 00:00', 5, NULL            , 5)
     , ('TAG-000479', '08/12/21 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', '12/31/24 00:00', '04/30/24 15:11', 1, '04/30/24 00:00', 6, NULL            , 6)
     , ('TAG-000479', '08/12/21 00:00', '11/06/23 19:31', '12/31/24 00:00', '06/10/24 17:02', 0, '06/10/24 00:00', 7, NULL            , 7)
     , ('TAG-001832', '03/28/24 00:00', '01/17/24 15:41', '03/31/24 00:00', '03/28/24 03:32', 1, '03/28/24 00:00', 1, '03/28/24 00:00', 1)
     , ('TAG-003420', '06/24/24 00:00', '06/24/24 18:55', '12/15/24 00:00', '06/25/24 15:18', 1, '06/24/24 00:00', 1, '06/24/24 00:00', 1);


thank you for helping, the code seems to be working 99% correctly. You wrote, "The concept seems pretty simple though...grab the earliest 'on_rent' date and the oldest 'off_rent' date. Then do the datediff calculations using those?" This is incorrect. Users can switch on-rent (1) and off-rent (0) multiple times. For example, TA-000479 is missing 966 days. The correct number is 1033, and here is the formula:  DATEDIFF(DAY,'8/12/2021','4/4/2024') = 966
DATEDIFF(DAY,'04/04/2024','06/10/2024') = 67

I'll see if I can come up with a new query, but in the meantime, you need to update your screenshot to represent what you're asking and use better sample data. There is no gap in time between when 'TAG-000479' switched to off-rent and then back on-rent. So because there is no gap, my code correctly calculated 1,033 days. The issue you are talking about is much more involved in order to detect and calculate the start/end dates within the sections.

@ATL-JP FYI, I wrote a new version of the query, updated above.

@ATL-JP I'm not seeing what you're seeing. I just ran my query and it is returning exactly the same values that are in your sample "Final Result" table....

the query ran, but the numbers are off. I have verified the data inserted into the table above, and it is all correct. The only correct number is 1033 from the result of your query; the other numbers are off by one.
It is one day more. They should match the data below.
+-------------+-----------------+
| DaysOnRent  | DaysOffRent    |
+-------------+-----------------+
|     1033         | 38          |
|      112          |           |
|       24        |           |
+-------------+-----------------+

@ATL-JP My query returns exactly those same numbers based on the sample data in my answer.

@ATL-JP The only thing that would cause this to be off by one is a timezone issue. Which means your server is in a timezone ahead of you. For example, I just ran this on a server that is configured to UTC and the values are now 1033, 113, 25. Whereas when I run it on a server configured for ET, it is 1033, 112, 24.

@ATL-JP if the values stored in your table are of a certain time zone and you need perfectly accurate values, then you need to adjust the query to be time zone aware. But that is a can of worms that won't be resolved here because it would need to account for daylight saving time and may even change depending on whether you are storing the local time (aka, each row could have a different time offset) vs UTC. That's on you to figure out though.

You are correct, Chad. I totally forgot about the UTC time. Thank you for helping solve this issue.
